mint authority revoke during minting
I want to mint tokens by revoking a freeze authority and the mint authority using the SPL library. However, I don't understand how to revoke the mint authority. Should I mint the tokens first and then revoke the mint authority, or is there another way?

createInitializeMintInstruction(
    mintKeypair.publicKey,
    tokenSupply.numDecimals,
    mintAuthority,
    null, // Freeze authority
    TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
);

